# TabBar Controller and NavigationBar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, tabbar

i need to build an app with a Tab Bar Controller and some view controllers, i have done almost all the code and now i am experiencing problems in pushing a viewcontroller from the first TableView (in the first image) because i can hide the tab bar but cannot show my navigationbar with the relative back button.

i just ask here if someone can help me and maybe explain me how to build the structure in IB (and code too), just the structure because all the rest i have done. Thanks!

[image of the App structure](http://gahan.altervista.org/andrea/tabbar/foto2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the UITableView in you first window, you are going to have to make your .h file be a subclass of UITableViewController and add all the necessary methods to your .m

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController {

}

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"


@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

@end
```

Now you'll have a tableview in your first view.  Then all you have to push the next view is something like:

```
NextViewController *next = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[next setTitle:@"Next View"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
[next release];
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me! now i am not sure if this will work in all my app but i am in this..

Answer (score 0):

NavigationViewController and TabViewController ,they are both container view controller.
So you must make scence about their hierarchy.

According to your image,I think the out-side view you should use is TabBarViewController.

first, make it as a rootviewcontroller to the window object.

```
 UITabBarController*tabCtrl = [[UITabBarController] alloc] init];
 self.window.rootViewController = tabCtrl;
```

second,make the first view controlelr as a UINavigationController,then add it into the tabbarcontroller.

```
UINavigationController *firstCtrl = UINavigationController  init...
firstCtrl.rootViewController = firstTableViewController// this is the table view that you want to show on the first tab.
```